# How to upgrade azure CI to use c# 8.0

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have an azure pipeline that builds my asp.net core 2.2 project.  I upgraded the project use c# 8.0.  However, my azure pipelines don't seem to support c# 8.0.  How do I upgrade my azure pipeline to use c# 8.0?

I have looked through the options in the azure pipeline and have not found anything on upgrading to c# 8.0

Here is the generated YAML file

```
pool:
  name: Hosted VS2017
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    vstsFeed: '3e219c03-bc0d-4106-82be-9ff3b21190a5'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
     !**\obj\**
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    diagnosticsEnabled: True
  enabled: false

- task: PublishSymbols@2
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
    PublishSymbols: false
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

I expect the project to build, but it gives me this error:
`CSC : error CS1617: Invalid option '8.0' for /langversion. Use '/langversion:?' to list supported values.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  Based on the YAML file, I am using the "Hosted 2017" agent pool.  After I changed this to "Azure Pipelines" with the "windows-2019" specification, it worked.

Comment: A list of available agents can be seen at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops

Comment: In the case of an Xamarin.iOS build, the "Hosted macOS" is required (at least for Apple certs, but most probably for building the Xamarin.iOS solution as this is required via VS). How to address the same issue here as there is no 2019 option?

Comment: @ChrisEvans any chance you can post the exact text you used?? "Azure Pipeline" with "windows 2019" specification are not valid options, according to Oliver's link.

Comment: I think it was windows-2019 @emery.noel